# ¿Cómo agrego $curauth a una página en Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

He creado una página en Wordpress llamada Mi cuenta. ( misitio.com/mi-cuenta )
Entre varios enlaces que voy a colocar, quisiera colocar en esa página un enlace que diga (VER MIS ENTRADAS)
Soy aficionado, he visto que el el codex de Wordpress existe una opción llamada $curauth que brinda la información al usuario que ha hecho Login.
Es decir, cada usuario que ingresa a la pagina (misitio.com/mi-cuenta) vea por ejemplo, su  nombre ( Display Name ) su avatar y un enlace que diga Ver mis entradas, tengo ya 3 dias de estar buscando la manera y no lo logro.
Si alguien me pudiera ayudar con esto se lo agradecería mucho de verdad

Comment: Hice un Template llamado Mi Cuenta y Lo logre relizar de dos maneras, la primera es `<a href="<?php echo home_url() . '/author/' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', wp_get_current_user()->ID ); ?>" >Ver mi Perfil Publico</a>`

La otra manera es `<?php 
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();?>
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($current_user->ID); ?>" >Ver mi Perfil Publico</a> `

Las dos funcionan , sin embargo no se cual es la correcta